# How can we version our library built only with headers using CMAKE?

Tags: cmake

How can we version our library built only with header (INTERFACES). I tried using set_target_properties but cmake throws error saying only whitelisted properties can only be set. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to set the `VERSION` property, as no binary will be generated, so there will be nothing that could carry the version information anyway.

You can still use [`write_basic_package_version_file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/module/CMakePackageConfigHelpers.html?command:write_basic_package_version_file#command:write_basic_package_version_file) to allow your clients to check your library's version when pulling it in through `find_package`.

Comment: Thank you. As i would be giving out the header files for third party with exe and meanwhile i will be adding new methods to the header files. Inorder to maintain track I want the third party to use specific header files with the exe.